# Angular 2 with CodeIgniter

Tags: javascript, php, angular, codeigniter

I searched a lot but unable to find the solution for this.

In angular 1.x, I used to include js in php pages and load the pages from server side code like CodeIgniter controller.

In **angular 2.x**, I unable to figure out that how I use server side features like $_SESSION?

e.g. I want to insert the data to mysql table and I will send data using POST service of Angular 2. How can I achieve that which user is logged in and created that record??

```
$city = $this->input->post("city");
$specialty= $this->input->post("specialty");

$data = array("city"=>, "specialty"=>$specialty, "createdBy"=>$this->session->userdata("userid"));

$this->db->insert("citywise", $data);
```

How to get this `$this->session->userdata("userid");` because application is loading at client and everything is handling like REST services.

Using `localStorage` I can get login data on client browser but what about server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use JWT(Json Web Token) for the same purpose 
refer this [link](https://github.com/ParitoshVaidya/CodeIgniter-JWT-Sample)